# Weird Image compression with \includegraphics

Tags: includegraphics, resolution

I'm using LaTeX for a lot of chemistry stuff so I include lots of reaction mechanisms which are saved in .png.
These files usually have a width of 10,000 pixels.
If I include them with

```
\includegraphics[\width=0.75\textwidth]{}
```

they have a very bad quality in the output pdf.
Ist there any explanation for that or even better a fix?

*picture out of the  molecule draw software, resolution: 12138 x 2118 pixels:*
[image: picture out of the molecule draw software, resolution: 12138 x 2118 pixels]

*Output in LaTeX pdf on DIN A4*
[image: Output in LaTeX pdf on DIN A4]

PS: It doesnt matter if I use width=, scale= or Height=. The output is always bad.

Comment: I have no idea how "resolution: 12138 x 2118 pixels" might translate into an actual width or height. What's the *natural* width of your image, in either centimeters or inches? And, do you down-sample the resolution before you save the image as a png file?

Comment: scaling bitmaps always has the potential to do this. if possible generate the images on a scalable format or failing that s higher resolution bitmap

Comment: The number of pixels is irrelevant, you have to look to the PPI (pixel per inch) or DPI (dot per inch) of the images, but if you want real quality, forget the png images and use vectorial pdf images, or better,  do no use images. In case of chemistry documents, is mandatory start with a `texdoc chemfig` and visit also [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/topic/chemistry) before to do too much without be sure if you are using the best tools.

Comment: Does it matter whether you use latexpdf or latex->ps->pdf (because the last is just asking for trouble).

Comment: What software are you using? All of the leading ones I know are capable of exporting vecgtor graphics

Comment: I wanted to close this issue but a admin forced me not to so I'll write it as a comment:
SOLVED
The chemistry software doesn't allow me to control DPI therefore I now save the files as svg. svg import doesn't work in LaTeX for mysteroíous reasons. if I need a tranparent background I open the vector in inkscape and save it at 600 dpi which works fine.
If I don't need transparent background I save it as eps right from the drawing software.
Also thanks for the advice on CTAN/chemistry - I'll look into that but am required to use a certain software for chemical drawing supplied by university.